# Unable to import a class in "Referenced libraries" after "Add Class Folder" in "Java Build Path" Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to include package X in project B as reference in my project A. Both project A and B are in my same workspace. Both A and B are Android/ Java projects.

I click on "**Add Class Folder**" in "**Java Build Path**" in Eclipse and choose package X folder and now it appears under "**Referenced libraries**" in my project A:
[image]

```
Reference Libaries
   src/[path-to-package-X]
```

Now I'm not able to import a class in that folder. Eclipse is not making any suggestion either.

```
import sg.xxx.xxx.xxx.ABaseClass;//sg.xxx.xxx.xxx is the package X  
==> The import "sg" cannot be resolved
```

Why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong here?

*Notes:
Project B is huge so I only want to include package X but not anything else.

Comment: `import sg.xxx.xxx.xxx.ABaseClass;`: Is `ABaseClass` located at `src/sg/xxx/xxx/xxx/ABaseClass`?

Comment: Yes and no, @user2558882. Yes, definitely, for project B. The whole package X appears under `src/...`  under Referenced Libraries in project A now so maybe yes for project A too? This is what I need help with

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to add the project as a "referenced" project in {project} / right-click / Properties / Java Build Path / Projects / Add.

Another alternative is to keep producing `.jar`s and add them as libraries.  Useful is this part of the code is stable enough.

Comment: Hi @MarioRossi, can I create `.jar` file for just package X but nothing else in project B and use that `.jar` file as libraries for project A?

Comment: Bad idea.  Think of the Java Build Path as what you'd specify as the classpath, both when compiling and running.  You don't specify a package's folder, you specify the one that's the parent of the first segment in the package name.

Comment: @fuzzybee  As @nitind mentions, it will become very confusing later if you generate `.jar`s with part of your projects.  Split the project in parts and plan for having one and only one `.jar` per project.

Comment: @fuzzybee  Glad to help.  And thanks to @ nitind for his contribution.